# How to find a unique element in the three-element array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a 3 element tuple where one of the elements is dissimilar from the other two. For example, it could be something like: `(0.456, 0.768, 0.456)`.

What is the easiest way to find the index of this dissimilar element? One way I can think of is consider index `(0, 1)` and `(1, 2)` and one of these will be dissimilar. If it is `(0, 1)` then compare their elements to the element at `2` otherwise, compare elements of `(1, 2)` to index `0` to find the dissimilar element.

Feels like I am missing a pythonic way to do this.

Comment: You could do `[my_tuple.count(x) for x in my_tuple].index(1)` but I'm not sure i'd prefer that over your approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could count the occurences of each element in the list then find the index of the place where only one element exists but I have a feeling this may not be as performant as your solution. It also wouldn't work if all 3 values are distinct.

```
my_tuple[[my_tuple.count(x) for x in my_tuple].index(1)]
```

Comment: *if all 3 values are distinct.* - there is no answer for the question :)

Comment: @splash58 - Well at that point all 3 would be dissimilar so I'm not sure what the op would want to return :)

Comment: Yeah, considering it is just 3 items, I will use this one liner :) Performance is not so much of a concern :)

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach:

```
def func(arr):
    x, y, z = arr
    return 2 * (x == y) + (x == z)
```

Test:

```
func(['B', 'A', 'A'])
# 0

func(['A', 'B', 'A'])
# 1

func(['A', 'A', 'B'])
# 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
index = [my_tuple.index(i) for i in my_tuple if my_tuple.count(i) == 1][0]
```

I'm not sure it is great performance-wise though.

Answer (score 1):

What may look like A huge overkill in python 3, but couldn't help posting:

```
import collections
a = (0.768, 0.456, 0.456)
print("Dissimilar object index: ", a.index(list(collections.Counter(a).keys())[list(collections.Counter(a).values()).index(1)]))
```

*Explanation:*

`collections.Counter(a)`: will return a frequency dict e.g `{0.768:1, 0.456:2}` etc. Then we just create a list to leverage `index(1)` to find out the value that's odd one out. Then we use `a.index(odd_one_out_val)` to find index.